# How to do exception handling in flux

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

Exception is thrown from one flux but second flux is not able to catch it. Is there anything missing in this code?

````
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Flux<Integer> fluxFromJust = Flux.just(1, 2,3,4,5);
                fluxFromJust.doOnNext(t -> {
                    try {
                        test();
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                       //System.out.println("------hello-------");
                    }
                }).subscribe();
            }
        
            public static void test() throws Exception{
                Flux<Integer> fluxFromJust = Flux.just(1, 2,3,4,5)
                        .concatWith(Flux.error(new RuntimeException("Test")))
                        .concatWith(Flux.just(6))
                        .map(i->i*2)
                        .onErrorMap(e -> new Exception(e) );
                fluxFromJust.subscribe();
            }
        }```
Catch of the calling function is not called. Is there anything missing?
````

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the code until it either starts doing what you expect, or it reveals where the problem lies? There is so much in there it's very unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to validate in this example. `doOnNext` is for side-effect operations (e.g. logging, metrics, etc) and not for executing logic, especially reactive code. `subscribe()` is async and using `subscribe` everywhere is also a hint that something is wrong. Ideally, you should subscribe once. I can't really understand your example and what you are trying to achieve here but try to combine 2 `Flux` using reactive operators and then subscribe.